# Problem running Nodemon: "[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, nodemon

I am setting up a server and every time I try running `npm start` I get the following error:

```
[nodemon] 2.0.12
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter 
`rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`      
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

I have researched online such as StackOverflow, YouTube and even Reddit. However I do not understand why I am getting this error, since I added `app.listen()`. I have also ran `npm update`to make sure that I have the most up to date npm version.

In addition, it seems that I need to revert to an older version of Nodemon, but I am wondering if there is a better way of doing this with more recent versions?

**Here is what my code looks like**:

index.js:

```
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import cors from "cors";

const app = express();

app.use(express.json({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
app.use(cors());

// database connection string: PLEASE NOTE THAT I HAVE REPLACED MY PASSWORD WITH THE PROPER ONE HERE
const CONNECTION_URL =
  "mongodb+srv://admin2021:<password>@cluster0.haf0y.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

// connect to database
mongoose
  .connect(CONNECTION_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() =>
    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port: ${PORT}`))
  )
  .catch(() => (error) => console.log(error.message));
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon ./index.js"
  },
  // etc.
}
```

Please note that I tried replacing `nodemon ./index.js` with `nodemon index.js` but I obtain the same error.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the error in this?
nodemon is started and it is running. check the http://localhost:<port>/. but lt looks like it is not getting the correct index.js. please share your folder structure if it is not running in you port

Comment: Hi @sojin thank you for your answer, it is not running. If it were running, it would have displayed "Server running on port: 5000" as I have configured it to do so in my index.js. localhost:5000 cannot be reached. The folder structure is simple, I have 3 files in the same folder including index.js, package.json, and package-lock.json.

Comment: `.catch(() => (error) => console.log(error.message));` is wrong, that should be just  `.catch((error) => console.log(error.message));`. Now see whether you're getting an error message - probably port 5000 is already in use or something like that.

Comment: Hi @Bergi oh wow that worked. I am very new to all this, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// connect to database
try {
  await mongoose.connect(url, options);
} catch (error) {
  console.log('connnection error', error)
}
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port: ${PORT}`))
```

Try this